# logger in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have this shell script which is supposed to log in a custom log file

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG=/var/log/Custom/rules.log
logger -f $LOG "found rule --> rule 0f 1"
```

Why it do not log into /var/log/Custom/rules.log file? But instead it logs into /var/log/syslog.

Please let me know what is wrong in my command.

Answer (score 0):

You probably misunderstood the `-f` parameter. Files passed with `-f` will be logged *into* /var/log/syslog, not logged *to* as the man page states.

> -f, --file file Log the of  the  specified  file.This option cannot be combined with a command-line message.

The following example will simply append your log string to `$LOG` using redirection.

```
echo "found rule --> rule 0f 1" >> $LOG
# with fancy timestamp:
echo "$(date) $(hostname): found rule --> rule 0f 1" >> $LOG
```

Comment: Yes, but I want logger to log in some file.
All my local0 to local7 are also used in rsyslog.conf

Comment: Why do you need logger to log to another file?

Comment: It prints time and other things which gives log file the look it should be, other ways to achieve it is very tedious

Comment: It's still the simplest solution to make your own timestamp and add other info manually.

Comment: `logger` is a "shell command interface to the syslog(3) system log module" according to its manual page. It is not a general purpose logging framework. If you want to log to a specific file, then use output redirection instead of `logger`...